# [error reducing techinique in lattice based commitment]

Tags: homomorphic-encryption, lattice-crypto, commitments, lwe

I am aware there are many techniques to reduce the error of lattice-based homomorphic encryption. But is there any technique to deal with lattice-based homomorphic commitment, e.g., [More Efficient Commitments from
Structured Lattice Assumptions](https://eprint.iacr.org/2016/997.pdf)

TIA